# Optimising loop: simple operations but large number of iterations taking long

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization

I am running a piece of Matlab code that is taking almost 70 hours and I'm sure there's a more efficient way of scripting it, but I cannot figure out how.
Looping over 1 iteration takes 1 second. The problem of course is that length(i) is 186144.

```
braindip = normrnd(0, 50, 186144,3);
nobrain = normrnd(0, 45, 25014656,3);

ok = 1; 
alpha = 2;
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');
dip_away = nan(size(braindip));
for i = 1:size(braindip,1)
  tic
  h_norm = repmat(braindip(i,:), size(nobrain,1),1);
  nn = sqrt(sum((h_norm - nobrain).^2,2));

  if min(nn) > alpha
    dip_away(ok,:) = braindip(i,:);
    ok = ok+1;
  end
  toc
  waitbar(i / size(braindip,1))
end
```

Does any one have a clever suggestion for optimising this loop? Thanks very much!

Comment: Just realized you are looking for closest points. `dsearchn` is probably faster then coding it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MATLAB 2016b or later, which supports automatic  broadcasting, you can change:

```
h_norm = repmat(braindip(i,:), size(nobrain,1),1);
nn = sqrt(sum((h_norm - nobrain).^2,2));
```

to

```
nn = sqrt(sum((braindip(i,:) - nobrain).^2,2));
```

A second option would be, to eliminate the sqrt. Use:

```
nn_qbd = sum((braindip(i,:) - nobrain).^2,2);
if min(nn_qbd) > alpha_qbd
```

Where `alpha_qbd=alpha.^2`, obviously calculated only once in advance. This leads to the third step, no need to store nn_qbd in a variable. You are only interested in the minimum:

```
nn_qbd_min = min(sum((braindip(i,:) - nobrain).^2,2));
if nn_qbd_min > alpha_qbd
```

Comparing the original code to the third option, the execution time is roughly cut in half.

Comment: `bsxfun()` is also an option that is supported on older versions.